# override alert() function for a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, overriding, alert

I am basically trying to prevent any custom dialog boxes to be shown in my webpage. 
***Basically third party ad-networks, which at times may use some malicious code to show alert() to the end user.***

I've come across a simple way, to override the alert on the main page:

`Window.prototype.alert = function() {console.log("alert prevented!")}`
So for a basic html page like this, it works just fine:

`<html>
    <body>
      <script>
      Window.prototype.alert = function() {console.log("an alert was averted");}
      </script>

  <div>
    <a onclick="alert(1)"> This is an alert inside the body</a>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>`

But introduce an iframe in the picture, and the alert within the iframe would pop-up.

What I still want to achieve is, if there is an `<iframe>` or anything similar HTML component, which basically would create a separate window, should also not be allowed to display any alert().
I'm not quite sure if this is possible, but still any suggestions?

Comment: can be the solution in jquery?

Comment: If can't be done through any plain & direct js code, then if achievable by jquery, please go ahead & provide the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not possible for old browsers, but newer browsers honor the [`sandbox`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-iframe-sandbox) attribute in `iframe`. “Newer” means IE 10 or newer or any reasonable new version of Chrome or Firefox. See [support details](http://caniuse.com/iframe-sandbox).

For example, if you wish to disallow popups only, use this:

```
<iframe src=foo.html sandbox=
  "allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin
   allow-scripts allow-top-navigation."></iframe>
```

Here I have listed all the possible values that this attribute value may contain except `allow-popups`, so that’s the only feature that will be disabled by the attribute.

Comment: Thanks @Jukka. But my requirement is mainly for mobile webkit browsers(iOS,Android). I don't have tight control on the properties of iframe here, as the ad-tags being used are javascript tags of third parties, and in some cases they give an irrational pop-up to the user within an iframe.